# Flutter Text Editor for huge text

Tags: flutter, performance, textfield, desktop-application

I need a code editor that handles huge code (like clob column) for the Flutter desktop application(Windows and macOS). I have used Flutter code editor (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_code_editor) as well. In this editor, everything is awesome except the performance. The current Text field of Flutter does not support the huge text.

Does anybody suggest a good editor for handling the huge text with syntax highlighting (Desktop application)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems to be an open issue in the Flutter framework https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/90063 and not in the package.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package
pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/code_editor

Here's an example of how you can use the code_editor package:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:code_editor/code_editor.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CodeEditor(
          model: CodeEditorModel(
            fileExtension: '.dart', // Specify the file extension for syntax highlighting
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the above code but I got an error    (The method 'CodeEditorModel' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'CodeEditorModel'.)

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3693], locale en-IN)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.85.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

Comment: I tried the example code from this package (pub. dev) and it is also slow since my text content has 25426 characters and 1030 lines. There is a delay while typing. is there any way to speed up the typing speed?